# Problems with custom AEM RTE PARAGRAPH FORMATS with Strong tag

Tags: adobe, aem, rte

I hope you can help me, my problem is when I configure in the rte a custom paragraph format and define "strong" tag, there is a conflict with bold feature because this option is automatically selected, and I don't want to this happen.

I based in this guide:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html#Paragraph Formats

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are duplicating existing functionality. If you do not wish to use the Bold button in the RTE you can disable it in the rtePlugins config. See "[format](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html#RTE%20Plugins%20and%20the%20features%20Property)" in the PluginID column.

You could then add your strong tag to the paraformat list as described in the [article you originally referenced](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html#Paragraph).